# I want to use multiple classes request in RequestBodyAdvice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this sample code that filters the Question.class using RequestBodyAdvice.

My question is how can I use this same Advice with multiple Request almost similar to Question.class. For example I have, **Question**, **Question2**, **Question3** clasess. most of their attribute are pretty similar.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomRequestBodyAdvice implements RequestBodyAdvice {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        System.out.println("In supports() method of " + getClass().getSimpleName());
        return methodParameter.getContainingClass() == QuestionController.class && targetType.getTypeName() == Question.class.getTypeName();
    }

    @Override
    public HttpInputMessage beforeBodyRead(HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType,
                                           Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("In beforeBodyRead() method of " + getClass().getSimpleName());
        return inputMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType,
                                Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        System.out.println("In afterBodyRead() method of " + getClass().getSimpleName());
        if (body instanceof Question) {
            Question question = (Question) body;
            question.setDate(new Date());
            return question;
        }

        return body;
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleEmptyBody(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType,
                                  Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        System.out.println("In handleEmptyBody() method of " + getClass().getSimpleName());
        return body;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce an interface for all your questions.

```java
public interface QuestionInterface {
  void setDate(Date date);
}
```

Implement in on all the questions and than you can us it instead of the concrete question class.

```java
if (body instanceof QuestionInterface ) {
    QuestionInterface question = (QuestionInterface) body;
    question.setDate(new Date());
    return question;
}
```

For the `Type` class you can cast it to `Class` and detect if it's assignable from the interface.

```java
boolean isSupportedClass = false;
if(type instanceof Class) {
    Class typeClass = (Class) type;
    isSupportedClass = typeClass.isAssignableFrom(QuestionInterface.class);
}
return methodParameter.getContainingClass().equals(QuestionController.class) && isSupportedClass;
```

Comment: Also how about this line of code? return methodParameter.getContainingClass() == QuestionController.class && targetType.getTypeName() == Question.class.getTypeName();

Should I define all the class using OR condition?

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: `isSupportedClass = typeClass.isAssignableFrom(QuestionInterface.class);` is returning false.